F# Azure Functions - Isolated Process SignalR Negotiation
I am in the process of converting an earlier version of an F# In-Process Azure Functions to an Isolated Process, and I'm running into a variety of issues that I'm struggling with.
One of them is here in regards to trying to set up a custom Negotiation process with new patterns that I'm finding examples of (Only in C#).
I don't know if this is my understanding of Class-Inheritance within F# (I don't really use any Classes in my own logic, but I need to use this for putting out this Isolated Process).
Essentially, I am trying  to create a NegotiateInfo through the actual process, but I am unable to access the NegotiateAsync base class, as it says it is not accessible. I don't know what I'm doing wrong, as I'm just following C# examples and converting to F#, but I cannot access this.
open System.Net
open System.Threading.Tasks
open Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker
open Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.Http
open Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Worker.SignalRService
open Microsoft.Extensions.Logging

//[<SignalRConnection("AzureSignalRConnectionString")>]
type SignalRNegotiateFunction(loggerFactory: ILoggerFactory, hub : ServiceHubContext, serviceProvider: IServiceProvider) =
    inherit ServerlessHub(serviceProvider: IServiceProvider)

    let logger = loggerFactory.CreateLogger<SignalRNegotiateFunction>()

    [<Function("SignalRNegotiate")>]
    member _.Run([<HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "negotiate")>] req: HttpRequestData) : Task<HttpResponseData> =
        task {

            let translator = req |> RequestHandler.determineTranslator
            let! remoteHubConnectionRequest = RequestHandler.decodeAsyncHubConnection translator req

            let userIdStr = remoteHubConnectionRequest.UserID
            let attribute = userIdStr |> Negotiator.infoAttributeFromUserIdStr

            let negoptions = new NegotiationOptions ()
            do negoptions.UserId <- userIdStr

            let negotiateResponse = base.NegotiateAsync(negoptions);

The very last line is where I am running into an error. ANY insight, would be highly appreciated!
The specific error that I'm running into is this:

Error FS0491  The member or object constructor 'NegotiateAsync' is not
accessible. Private members may only be accessed from within the
declaring type. Protected members may only be accessed from an
extending type and cannot be accessed from inner lambda expressions.


When you ask questions, read the guidelines. They tell you to include any error messages, and to share the minimum amount of code others need to reproduce your problem.

Appreciate the reminder. I should have done a better job of isolating this issue and creating reproducible code...  I have updated with the error at-least, and hopefully this can still be helpful!

I think the problem here is that you can't call a protected method from inside a task builder.
To work around this limitation, create a helper method:
    member this.MyNegotiateAsync(negoptions) =
        this.NegotiateAsync(negoptions)

Then call your helper method from within the task builder:
    [<FunctionName("SignalRNegotiate")>]
    member this.Run([<HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "post", Route = "negotiate")>] req: HttpRequestData) : Task<HttpResponseData> =
        task {

            let translator = req |> RequestHandler.determineTranslator
            let! remoteHubConnectionRequest = RequestHandler.decodeAsyncHubConnection translator req

            let userIdStr = remoteHubConnectionRequest.UserID
            let attribute = userIdStr |> Negotiator.infoAttributeFromUserIdStr

            let negoptions = new NegotiationOptions ()
            do negoptions.UserId <- userIdStr

            let negotiateResponse = this.MyNegotiateAsync(negoptions)


Thank you.  This is very helpful (both the reference and the example call)... Will be trying this out and informing how this works.
